# The Machine Translation Service is not running when it should be running error message

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, central-administration, configuration, app

I get this error in Central Administration.

**The Machine Translation Service is not running when it should be running**

It tells me to do the following:

"From the Central Admin UI, navigate to manage service applications. Click on the Machine Translation Service application. Enter a value in the timer job frequency and click OK."

I have followed the instructions but do not see the 'timer job frequency' field in the service details. I think I may be looking at it wrong...? Please help...

I see the following properties when I click on the service:

- Enable File Extensions
- Item Size Limits
- Online Translation Connection
- Translation Processes
- Translation Throughput
- Maximum Translation Attempts
- Maximum Synchronous Translation Requests
- Translation Quota
- Completed Job Expiration Time
- Recycle Threshold
- Office 97-2003 Document Scanning

Please assist in anyway you can. I am quite new to SharePoint, I've had maybe a bit of experience with 2010 but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I'm new to SharePoint, and got this error in the Central Administration Health Analyzer after a new install of 2013.

For me, this was an erroneous message - not an actual error. There was nothing wrong with the Machine Translation Service.

All I did was visit the page with the timer jobs (Monitoring > Review Job Definitions), and verify that the job ("Machine Translation Service - Machine Translation Service Timer Job") was set up and enabled. Then, I went into both the service properties and management of the service (via "Manage Service Applications" (Central Administration > Manage Service Applications (under the heading "Application Management")), as you did).

After doing this, I clicked "Reanalyze" on the Health Analyzer issue, and it miraculously went away. It may take a bit more wandering around through related properties, or a few times of reanalyzing and refreshing to get rid of the message, but, hopefully, this approach will sort it for you as it did for me.

Incidentally, the same thing happened with the Health Analyzer message regarding Missing Server Side Dependencies - Missing Web Part, which turned out to be to do with the Search Administration section, and, again, just needed the pages visiting, and a Reanalyze. Solution found here: http://davidmsterling.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/sharepoint-2013-missing-server-side.html

Hope this helps.